# ORA-04031: unable to allocate X bytes of shared memory

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-xe

Trying to start oracle service, shows me the follow error:

[image]

I have the follow SPFILEXE.ORA:

[image]

Im using ORACLE XE, but really I don't know which parameter change and what should be the value.

Please help !!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try doubling shared pool size to 1G, or 1000M.

Java pool should be larger if you're using EJB.

Large pool should be much larger if you're using RMAN.

Remove sessions.

Reduce processes by a LOT, like start with 200.  Are you ever going to use close to 10,000???  XE is not meant for that many processes.

Make job_queue about 20.

Answer (score 0):

I home you aren't trying to edit that spfile with a text editor!!  It is a binary file (in spite of so much clear text) and will be corrupted if you deliberately or inadvertently modify it directly.  I'd cut back on open_cursors, processes, and sessions.  I've only got open_cursors=300 on my big production databases; processes=150.